# DQN CartPole-v1 neural network doesn't optimize

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I'm doing my first dnq algorithm, I'm trying to build a dnq agent, and neural network from scratch, but it seems that neural network doesn't optimize, I did 2 hidden layers, with ReLU, and the output layer with linear activation function, but often the weights diverge to NaN, or when the loss function decrease, the total_reward/steps doesn't increase, I don't know why, I debugged a lot, the code is below the logic should be like this code that I found https://github.com/abhavk/dqn_from_scratch/blob/master/cartpole.py which works fine, I don't know where I'm wronging...
I didn't use replay memory for this, I think it should be work without at least

Or in colab you can try this (neural network that doesn't work... with other code in internet)

```py
import random
import gym
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import pickle as pk

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, n_neurons: np.array, path: str = None):
        """
        args:
            n_neurons: np.array
                number of neurons per layer
            path: path to weights and biases dumped
        """
        self.n_neurons = n_neurons
        if path == None:
            self.biases = [np.random.uniform(low=-0.5, high=0.5, size=(layer)) for layer in n_neurons[1:]]
            self.weights = [np.random.uniform(low=-0.5, high=0.5, size=(n_neurons[i+1], n_neurons[i])) for i in range(len(n_neurons) - 1)]
        else:
            with open(path, "rb") as file:
                self.weights, self.biases = pk.load(file)

    def predict(self, input: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Args:
            input: np.ndarray 1dim
                array that rapresent inputs
        Return:
            prediction: np.ndarray 1dim
        """
        for weights, biases, activation_function in zip(self.weights, self.biases, self.activation_functions):
            input = activation_function(weights.dot(input) + biases)
        return input

    def forward_propagate(self, input: np.array):
        """
        Args:
            input: np.ndarray 1dim
                array that rapresent inputs
        Return: predict values
            a, z
        """
        z = [input]
        a = [input]
        for weights, biases, activation_function in zip(self.weights, self.biases, self.activation_functions):
            z_ = weights.dot(input) + biases
            z.append(z_)
            input = activation_function(z_)
            a.append(input)
        return z, a
    
    def backpropagate(self, z: list, a: list, target_output: np.array, learning_rate: float):
        print(self.biases)
        if any([any([any(np.isnan(weights)) for weights in weights]) for weights in self.weights]) or any([any(np.isnan(biases)) for biases in self.biases]):
            print('nan weights or biases')
            raise Exception('NNNNNNOOOOOONNNNNNNNNEEEEEEEEEEEEE')
        """
        Args:
            z: list[np.ndarray]
            a: list[np.ndarray]
            target_output: np.array
            learning_rate: float
        """
        # compute last layer gradients
        gradients_a = self.cost_function_derivative(a[-1], target_output)
        gradients_z = gradients_a * self.activation_functions_derivative[-1](z[-1])
        
        # update weights and biases, and compute gradients for hidden layers
        for weights, biases, z, a_, activation_function_derivative in reversed(list(zip(self.weights[1:], self.biases[1:], z[1:-1], a[1:-1], self.activation_functions_derivative[:-1]))):
            weights -= learning_rate * gradients_z.reshape(-1, 1).dot(a_.reshape(1, -1))
            biases -= learning_rate * gradients_z
            gradients_a = weights.T.dot(gradients_z)
            gradients_z = gradients_a * activation_function_derivative(z)

        #update first weights and biases
        self.weights[0] -= learning_rate * gradients_z.reshape(-1, 1).dot(a[0].reshape(1, -1))
        self.biases[0] -= learning_rate * gradients_z
    def save(self, path: str):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            pk.dump((self.weights, self.biases), file)


class CustomNeuralNetwork(NeuralNetwork):
    def __init__(self, n_neurons: np.array, path: str):
        """
        args:
            n_neurons: np.array
                number of neurons per layer
            path: path to weights and biases dumped
        """
        super().__init__(n_neurons, path)


        def identity(x): return x
        def identity_derivative(x): return np.ones(len(x))

        def ReLU(x):
            return np.multiply(x,(x>0))
        def ReLU_derivative(x):
            return (x>0)*1

        def sum_square_error(predicted, target):
            return np.sum((predicted - target)**2) / 2
        def sum_square_error_derivative(predicted, target):
            return predicted - target
        
        """
        Define in object functions:
            activation_functions: iter[len(n_neurons)-1] dtype:function(np.array)->np.array
            activation_functions_derivative: iter[len(n_neurons)-1] dtype:function(np.array)->np.array
            cost_function_derivative: function(predicted: np.array, target: np.array)->np.array
                partial derivatives of cost_function respect to predicted values
        """
        self.activation_functions = [ReLU, ReLU, identity]
        self.activation_functions_derivative = [ReLU_derivative, ReLU_derivative, identity_derivative]
        self.cost_function = sum_square_error
        self.cost_function_derivative = sum_square_error_derivative



ENV_NAME = "CartPole-v1"

GAMMA = 0.95
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

MEMORY_SIZE = 1000000
BATCH_SIZE = 20

EXPLORATION_MAX = 1.0
EXPLORATION_MIN = 0.01
EXPLORATION_DECAY = 0.995


class DQNSolver:

    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space):
        self.exploration_rate = EXPLORATION_MAX

        self.action_space = action_space
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=MEMORY_SIZE)

        self.nn = CustomNeuralNetwork([observation_space, 24, 24, action_space], None)

        #self.model = Sequential()
        #self.model.add(Dense(5, input_shape=(observation_space,), activation="relu"))
        #self.model.add(Dense(24, activation="relu"))
        #self.model.add(Dense(self.action_space, activation="linear"))
        #self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() < self.exploration_rate:
            return random.randrange(self.action_space)
        q_values = self.nn.predict(state[0])
        return np.argmax(q_values)
        #q_values = self.model.predict(state)
        #return np.argmax(q_values[0])

    def experience_replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
            return
        batch = random.sample(self.memory, BATCH_SIZE)
        for state, action, reward, state_next, terminal in batch:
            q_update = reward
            if not terminal:
                q_update = (reward + GAMMA * np.amax(self.nn.predict(state_next[0])))
                #q_update = (reward + GAMMA * np.amax(self.model.predict(state_next)[0]))
            z, a = self.nn.forward_propagate(state[0])
            q_values = np.copy(a[-1])
            #q_values = self.model.predict(state)
            q_values[action] = q_update
            self.nn.backpropagate(z, a, q_values, LEARNING_RATE)
        self.exploration_rate *= EXPLORATION_DECAY
        self.exploration_rate = max(EXPLORATION_MIN, self.exploration_rate)


def cartpole():
    env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
    #score_logger = ScoreLogger(ENV_NAME)
    observation_space = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    action_space = env.action_space.n
    dqn_solver = DQNSolver(observation_space, action_space)
    run = 0
    while True:
        run += 1
        state = env.reset()
        state = np.reshape(state, [1, observation_space])
        step = 0
        while True:
            step += 1
            #env.render()
            action = dqn_solver.act(state)
            state_next, reward, terminal, info = env.step(action)
            reward = reward if not terminal else -reward
            state_next = np.reshape(state_next, [1, observation_space])
            dqn_solver.remember(state, action, reward, state_next, terminal)
            state = state_next
            if terminal:
                print("Run: " + str(run) + ", exploration: " + str(dqn_solver.exploration_rate) + ", score: " + str(step))
                #score_logger.add_score(step, run)
                break
            dqn_solver.experience_replay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cartpole()
```

source: https://github.com/LorenzoTinfena/deep-q-learning-itt-final-project/tree/main/src/core

And this work with keras neural network, why?? is really Adam optimizer??

````py
import random
import gym
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam


#from scores.score_logger import ScoreLogger

ENV_NAME = "CartPole-v1"

GAMMA = 0.95
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001

MEMORY_SIZE = 1000000
BATCH_SIZE = 20

EXPLORATION_MAX = 1.0
EXPLORATION_MIN = 0.01
EXPLORATION_DECAY = 0.995


class DQNSolver:

    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space):
        self.exploration_rate = EXPLORATION_MAX

        self.action_space = action_space
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=MEMORY_SIZE)

        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(observation_space,), activation="relu"))
        self.model.add(Dense(24, activation="relu"))
        self.model.add(Dense(self.action_space, activation="linear"))
        self.model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() < self.exploration_rate:
            return random.randrange(self.action_space)
        q_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(q_values[0])

    def experience_replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
            return
        batch = random.sample(self.memory, BATCH_SIZE)
        for state, action, reward, state_next, terminal in batch:
            q_update = reward
            if not terminal:
                q_update = (reward + GAMMA * np.amax(self.model.predict(state_next)[0]))
            q_values = self.model.predict(state)
            q_values[0][action] = q_update
            self.model.fit(state, q_values, verbose=0)
        self.exploration_rate *= EXPLORATION_DECAY
        self.exploration_rate = max(EXPLORATION_MIN, self.exploration_rate)


def cartpole():
    env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
    #score_logger = ScoreLogger(ENV_NAME)
    observation_space = env.observation_space.shape[0]
    action_space = env.action_space.n
    dqn_solver = DQNSolver(observation_space, action_space)
    run = 0
    while True:
        run += 1
        state = env.reset()
        state = np.reshape(state, [1, observation_space])
        step = 0
        while True:
            step += 1
            #env.render()
            action = dqn_solver.act(state)
            state_next, reward, terminal, info = env.step(action)
            reward = reward if not terminal else -reward
            state_next = np.reshape(state_next, [1, observation_space])
            dqn_solver.remember(state, action, reward, state_next, terminal)
            state = state_next
            if terminal:
                print("Run: " + str(run) + ", exploration: " + str(dqn_solver.exploration_rate) + ", score: " + str(step))
                #score_logger.add_score(step, run)
                break
            dqn_solver.experience_replay()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cartpole()
```
````